# Unknown column in 'where-clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have simple sql:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `oc_artists`
 WHERE `oc_artists`.`artist_id`=`oc_artists_tags`.`artist_id`
   AND `oc_artists_tags`.`artist_tag` LIKE '%klass%'
```

When I run this I got:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'oc_artists_tags.artist_id' in 'where clause'

This is a sql for a search script. I need simple return unique results from oc_artists if query matches with `oc_artists_tags`.`artist_tag`.

Comment: You need to JOIN the table oc_artists_tags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd join table is missing from your query, so `include oc_artists_tags` table in your join...

Finally your query should be-

```
SELECT *
  FROM `oc_artists`, `oc_artists_tags`
 WHERE `oc_artists`.`artist_id`=`oc_artists_tags`.`artist_id`
   AND `oc_artists_tags`.`artist_tag` LIKE '%klass%'
```

You can also use join or inner join instead of comma join-

```
SELECT *
  FROM `oc_artists` as oa
  join `oc_artists_tags` as oat on oa.artist_id=oat.artist_id 
 WHERE oat.artist_tag LIKE '%klass%';
```

To gain performance follow below points-

1. You should select only required columns instead of *.
2. join fields must be indexed and better will be that these fields should be integer type.
3. If possible avoid '%'in left side in like clause as it will not use index and slow your query. for example artist_tag like 'klass%' will use index but '%klass%' will not.

Comment: I'll upvote if you also add a modern, explicit JOIN version of the query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to JOIN the table `oc_artists_tags` too and you can achieve this two way,

**Option 1**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `oc_artists`
  INNER JOIN `test2` on `oc_artists`.`artist_id`=`oc_artists_tags`.`artist_id`
  AND `oc_artists_tags`.`artist_tag` LIKE '%klass%'
```

**Option 2**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `oc_artists`,`oc_artists_tags`
  WHERE `oc_artists`.`artist_id`=`oc_artists_tags`.`artist_id`
  AND `oc_artists_tags`.`artist_tag` LIKE '%klass%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the other table.[Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) helps you.